# Detecting gyroscope data using promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, null, promise

In a plugin that I am currently authoring, I am using a function to check whether the device provides gyroscopic data. Although intuitively this can be easily resolved by checking the value of `window.DeviceOrientationEvent`, i.e.:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    // Ok, device orientation event listening is supported!
}
```

…this statement *also* resolves true when on **a device with no functional gyroscope**, i.e. Google Chrome on a laptop. The event data returned for alpha, beta and gamma are, however, `null`. Basically, the `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` does not tell me if there is gyroscopic data available, but only informs me if the browser/user-agent supports the event.

Therefore, not only do I have to check for support for the event, but also have to cross verify the value of alpha, beta or gamma such that they are not null. The best way I could check is using promises, which I feel a bit cumbersome and long-winded:

```
var check = {
    // Does it have a working gyroscope?
    gyroscope: function() {
        var d = new $.Deferred(),
            handler = function(e) {
                d.resolve({
                    alpha: e.alpha,
                    beta: e.beta,
                    gamma: e.gamma
                });
                // Listen to device orientation once and remove listener immediately
                window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', handler, false);
            };
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handler, false);
        return d;
    }
}

// Wait for gyroscope data
$.when(check.gyroscope()).done(function(r) {
    if(r.alpha === null && r.beta === null && r.gamma === null) {
        console.log('Device has no functional gyroscope.');
    } else {
        console.log('Device has functional gyroscope.')
    }
});
```

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this code?

Comment: For reference, [here's a library](https://github.com/tomgco/gyro.js) that seems to do much of the same, and is cross-browser (i.e. supports events with vendor prefixes)

Comment: @Flambino Wow, didn't know that library existed — should've googled a tad bit harder ;)

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's any good - just stumbled across it. I skimmed the code though, and it seems pretty neat and well-written. Figured you'd be interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I imagine you're still checking `window.DeviceOrientationEvent`? Because if that doesn't exist, you can presumably skip everything else.
- When using `$.Deferred` you should always return its `.promise()` - not the deferred object itself. The deferred object itself is "read/write" (i.e. you can call `resolve` and `reject` on it), while the promise it creates is "read-only" which is what you want to pass on to other code.
- You don't need `$.when` unless you're waiting for several promises to resolve. You can simple call `promise.done()` (or `.then` or `.fail` or `.always`)
- Since the idea is get a yes/no answer, I'd simply use the resolve/reject callbacks of the deferred and do all the checking in one place.
- I don't know if it's relevant, but checking strictly against `null` will give you a false positive if `alpha` etc.are actually completely `undefined`. It might be better to check `typeof alpha === 'number'`.
- Of course, you don't really *need* promises; a simple callback would do.

For instance:

```
var check = {
  gyroscope: function (callback) {
    function handler(event) {
      var hasGyro = typeof event.alpha === 'number'
                 && typeof event.beta  === 'number'
                 && typeof event.gamma === 'number';
      window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', handler, false);
      callback(hasGyro);
    }
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handler, false);
  }
};

check.gyroscope(function (hasGyroscope) {
  if(hasGyroscope) {
    console.log('Device has functional gyroscope.')
  } else {
    console.log('Device has no functional gyroscope.');
  }
});
```

If you do want to use `$.Deferred`, I'd recommend something like:

```
var check = {
  gyroscope: function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    function handler(event) {
      var hasGyro = typeof event.alpha === 'number'
                 && typeof event.beta  === 'number'
                 && typeof event.gamma === 'number';
      window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', handler, false);
      hasGyro ? deferred.resolve() : deferred.reject();
    }

    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handler, false);
    return deferred.promise();
  }
};

check.gyroscope().then(function () {
  console.log('Device has functional gyroscope.')
}, function () {
  console.log('Device has no functional gyroscope.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful input! I have to admit that I have unintentionally left out some important information—`$.when()` was used to check for other promises, too, and two of which are AJAX calls; and that I did do a basic `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` check, but left it out when I was reducing the code. And thanks for pointing out that I forgot to return the promise... and surprised that it still works when I forget to do so.

Comment: I learn from this, thanks. But something puzzles me: why to have a "double envelope" `var check = { gyroscope: function() {...} };` instead of something more simple like `var checkGyro = function() {...};` ?

Comment: @cFreed True, a plain function would work just as well. I just assumed that there might be other functions in that `check` namespace/object which were just left out in the question. So I just kept that structure intact, and focussed on the content.